# Add elements to xml file in java without loading it into memory

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have an application that generates very heavy xml files with lists of elements and I have to add elements to it in several steps and save them on hard disk. For example, in the first iteration the complete file would be generated:

```
<File>
    <Header>
        <Date>yyyy-MM-dd</Date>
        <Uuid>335773a6-1ee3-4ef8-95dd-65abed4226b4 </Uuid>
        <!-- Other params -->
    </Header>
    <Body>
    <!-- Other params -->
    <Users>
        <User>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Surname>Doe</Surname>
            <Mail>john@mail.com</Mail>
            <!-- Other params -->
        </User>
        <User>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Surname>Doe</Surname>
            <Mail>john@mail.com</Mail>
            <!-- Other params -->
        </User>
        <!-- Add more items here-->
    
    </Users>    
    </Body>
</File>
```

In the following iterations more elements are added (in the example only two more users):

```
<File>
    <Header>
        <Date>yyyy-MM-dd</Date>
        <Uuid>335773a6-1ee3-4ef8-95dd-65abed4226b4 </Uuid>
        <!-- Other params -->
    </Header>
    <Body>
    <!-- Other params -->
    <Users>
        <User>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Surname>Doe</Surname>
            <Mail>john@mail.com</Mail>
            <!-- Other params -->
        </User>
        <User>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Surname>Doe</Surname>
            <Mail>john@mail.com</Mail>
            <!-- Other params -->
        </User>
        <User>
            <Id>3</Id>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Surname>Doe</Surname>
            <Mail>john@mail.com</Mail>
            <!-- Other params -->
        </User>
        <User>
            <Id>4</Id>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Surname>Doe</Surname>
            <Mail>john@mail.com</Mail>
            <!-- Other params -->
        </User>     
        <!-- Add more items here-->
    
    </Users>    
    </Body>
</File>
```

As the files can be very long and I want to avoid memory problems, can I add new elements in the correct position without fully loading the file into memory?

Comment: Yes - assuming you are able to write code that (1) copies input to output until the correct position is reached, (2) write XML to the output, (3) copy the rest of the file to the output.  In very simple cases this may be ok - maybe you're just looking for the line <\Users> as the insertion point.

Comment: It is a good idea to find the position by the closing tag of the element. I'm going to try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [XML Streaming API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to maintain your document as two files: an outline file

```
<File>
    <Header>
        <Date>yyyy-MM-dd</Date>
        <Uuid>335773a6-1ee3-4ef8-95dd-65abed4226b4 </Uuid>
        <!-- Other params -->
    </Header>
    <Body>
      <!-- Other params -->
      <Users>
         &users;
      </Users>
    </Body>
</File>
```

and a payload file:

```
<User>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Surname>Doe</Surname>
    <Mail>john@mail.com</Mail>
    <!-- Other params -->
</User>
<User>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Surname>Doe</Surname>
    <Mail>john@mail.com</Mail>
    <!-- Other params -->
</User>
```

You can then simply append to the payload file. The outline file will need to declare the entity reference `&users;` in its DTD. Whenever you read the outline file with a conformant XML parser, the payload file will be pulled in automatically.

This doesn't work in an environment such as Javascript where XML external entities are not supported. Some sites also have security settings to prevent use of external entities.